# Any tag closed after span does not let span do it's required work

Tags: php, html

Whenever I have a span tag that colors my text green and there is a tag closing after span like:

```
  </strong> or </i> or </b>,
```

the span tag does not color the text green. The example code is:

```
  Newly written  <span style="color: green;"> <br /> <br /></span> <strong> 
  ab <span style="color: green;"> </strong> 
  <ol> <li> Marium </li> <li> <strong> Malik </strong> </li> <li> <strong>     
  This is new as well </strong> </strong> </li> </ol></span>
```

This code is auto generated by a function, that finds all the newly added strings and colors them green, so I cannot change HTML. Is there any solution to it?? 
I already know the problem of the tag closing after span and I already have mentioned that I cannot change my HTML, I just want to know whether there is any solution to it or not.

Can Php do something like whenever any tag is closing after span tag, it should switch their places?

Comment: You need to nest your tags properly
you can't `<strong><span></strong></span>` like you do...
You must `<strong><span></span></strong>` for instance

Comment: I am not doing it, my php code is finding the difference and doing it itself.

Comment: there is no such a thing... your php code is doing it by itself means you are doing it...
If not there then in the function you are using. Fix the function to fix the results.
html does not work as we want. It works as specified here http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/

Comment: All these tags are newly added ones, so it is considering them as newly added string so they are inside span. This is what I actually want and it is working in the same way exactly I want. But these HTML tags are messed up

Comment: As Julio states, the solution is to change the html. Don't ask a question asking for a solution and then reject the solution because you don't like the rules of HTML. Listen, think, do.

Comment: That's why I have asked for "Can Php do something like whenever any tag is closing after span tag, it should switch their places??"

Answer (score 0):

```
Newly written  <span style="color: green;"> IF ONLY YOU HAD TEXT HERE AND NOT EMPTY SPACES<br /> <br /></span> <strong> 
  ab <span style="color: green;"> EMPTY SPACES HERE, SO, NO COLOR</strong> 
  <ol> <li> Marium </li> <li> <strong> Malik </strong> </li> <li> <strong>     
  This is new as well </strong> </strong> </li> </ol></span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e0nL1ynt/

I don't know how the algorithm that generates this spans is working, but all I see is `<br>` and empty spaces being surrounded by the styled spans

Comment: But, logically it should color Marium, Malik and This is new as well, as span tag is closing after them.

Answer (score 0):

As Julio mentioned, you need the `<strong>` tag inside the `<span>` this change makes it work as you desired:

```
     Newly written  <span style="color: green;"> IF ONLY YOU HAD TEXT HERE AND NOT EMPTY SPACES<br /> <br /></span>  
  ab <span style="color: green;"> <strong>EMPTY SPACES HERE, SO, NO COLOR</strong> 
  <ol> <li> Marium </li> <li> <strong> Malik </strong> </li> <li> <strong>     
  This is new as well </strong> </strong> </li> </ol></span>
```

Comment: The word "ab" needs to be bold too, if strong tag is inside span, how would the word "ab" be bold?

Comment: It needs its own `<strong>` tag unless you are going to have all the `<span>` tags inside the `<strong>` tag.  However it sounds like everything is in span tags so just wrap each element in `<strong>` and `</strong>` tags.

Comment: I already know the problem of the tag closing after span and I already have mentioned that I cannot change my HTML, I just want to know whether there is any solution to it or not. I cannot change my HTML –

Comment: Write another function that takes the output of your original function and reformats it, but this is really getting to be a hack. PHP doesn't have a native function for that, you will have to write it, but it would be better to modify the original function if at all possible.

Comment: Yes, it would get more messier. but I think that's the only option left  now.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words, You cannot open a new tag before closing the the previous one.

Instead of this (with an empty space that won't show nothing in the first  ofcourse):

```
<span style="color: green;"> <br /> <br /></span> <strong> 
  ab <span style="color: green;"> </strong> 
  <ol> <li> Marium </li> <li> <strong> Malik </strong> </li> <li> <strong>     
  This is new as well </strong> </strong> </li> </ol></span>
```

Try this:

```
<span style="color: green;">Hello Marium<br /></span>
<strong> 
<span style="color: blue;">ab</span>
</strong> 
<ol>
  <li> Marium </li> 
  <li> 
  <strong> Malik </strong> 
  </li> 
  <li> 
  <strong> This is new as well </strong>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**OUTPUT:**

Hello Marium (Normal with green Color)

ab      (Normal with blue Color)

Marium  (Normal with default black color)

**Malik**   (Strong with default black color)

**This is new as well** (Strong with default black color)

[A Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvOwNJ)

**EDIT: 2**

*The word "ab" needs to be bold too, if strong tag is inside span, how would the word "ab" be bold?*

Well for that case wrap `<strong> ab </strong>` around it it would be fine since it needs its own `<strong>` tag.

```
<span style="color: green;">Hello Marium<br /></span>
    <strong> 
    <span style="color: blue;">
    <strong>ab</strong>
    </span>
    </strong> 
    <ol>
      <li> Marium </li> 
      <li> 
      <strong> Malik </strong> 
      </li> 
      <li> 
      <strong> This is new as well </strong>
      </li>
    </ol>
```

> Note: If the intention is to color them all with one single color, you
>   *do not* have to put so many `<span>` tags again and again but a single one would be fine:

An Example:

```
<span style="color: green;">Hello Marium<br />  <strong> 
    <strong>ab</strong>
    </strong> 
    <ol>
      <li> Marium </li> 
      <li> 
      <strong> Malik </strong> 
      </li> 
      <li> 
      <strong> This is new as well </strong>
      </li>
    </ol> 
</span>
```

[A Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvOwNJ)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your problem . I am agree with julio. The problem is `<strong><span>` formatting. You can look at here :

```
Newly written  <span style="color: green;"> <br /> <br /></span> <strong> 
ab <span style="color: green;">  </strong> 
<ol> <li> <strong> <span style="color: green;"> Malik </strong> </li> <li> <strong><span style="color: green;"> Malik </strong> </li> <li> <strong>     
<span style="color: green;">This is new as well </strong> </strong> </li></ol></span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/orvi2014/0674ck0u/